# Відповідники до слова "імпет"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, іменники, запозичені-слова

У творі О. Конського [Дід Євмен](http://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=4290) натрапила на таке речення:

> Очі у діда чорні, великі та лискучі такі; скине їми він на тебе – аж здригнеш, **наче** тебе **імпетом** з печі **вдарить**.

Розумію, що ***наче імпетом вдарить = сильно вдарить***. Про це читаю і в [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/impet):

> **І́МПЕТ**, у, чол., заст. Сильний натиск, раптовий порив; сила.

Цікавить, чи є ще якісь відповідники до слова "імпет", які б якнайточніше передали значення цього слова, зокрема у поданому мною контексті.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику чужомовних слів і термінів](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt)
 знаходжу:

> **імпет** - запал, натиск, потяг, поштовх, розмах, рушій, удар, див. *імпакт*.

Далі за [відсиланням](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt):

> **імпакт** - зудар, поштовх, сутичка, див. колізія.

Кожен із цих відповідників може підійти до поданого Вами контексту.